# Is an equivariance map a homomorphism map?

Tags: group-theory

$\Phi$ is said to be an equivariance map iff. $\rho(h)\Phi=\Phi\pi(h)$, $\forall h\in G$. G denotes a Group. $\rho$ and $\pi$ denote representations of the group.

But can we prove $\Phi \in Hom_G(\pi, \rho)$, which is given without proof in some literature. Is it correct? How can we prove it?

Comment: You should define $Hom_G(\pi, \rho)$ to make this question answerable.